# How to get App_Id for tagged?

Tags: android, metadata

I need to integrate Tagged Api with my application,but i dont have any other documents except http://www.tagged.com/api/spec.html,Please help from where can i get the application id?

Help me

Comment: (not sure)but for market package name is unique and identify as unique app.

Comment: bt the app is not published in market, and i dont get any idea how to get application id and user id....